# Can't push my changes to a branch

Tags: git, push

I hope someone can help me with this issue. I've been working on this specific project for a while now and only recently have I been getting this issue every time I try to push my changes to the remote branch.

[image]

It seems like it needs all other branches to be updated before I can push my latest changes on the current branch.

Comment: Did you try to "git pull"? Does this help?

Comment: @reto I need to checkout the devops branch and pull first before the other branch's push goes through.

Answer (score 0):

this means that on the other branches an update was committed. update your branches and merge if that is needed. when everything is up-to-date then you can post all your changes to the "remote" branch.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is I never had to do something like this before until only recently for some reason.

Comment: what for program do you use ? console? sourcetree?. if your new to git sourcetree is and GUI of your git repository where you can easily manage your commit,post and merges.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to push changes because your remote branch's commit is ahead  than what you are trying to push currently from local. If you squashed commits and try to push changes it will reject commits like that. You can do a safe  force push to that branch

```
git push <upstream name> +<branch name>
```